# NaN when running a once function

Tags: javascript, callback

I have made a function that is designed to execute a function once, and any future calls to the called function will result as the first call.

```
once = function(fun){
  var beenCalled = false;
  var answer;
  return function() {
    if (beenCalled === true) {
      return answer;
    } else {
      beenCalled = true;
      answer = fun();
      return answer;
    }
  }
};

var add = once(function(x,y,z) {
      return x + y + z;
});

console.log(add(1,2,3));
console.log(add(4,5,6));
```

I am expecting the console to log '6' and '6', instead it is logging 'Nan' and 'NaN' and I am not sure why. I am pretty sure that the issue is with the 'answer = fun();' line, but I am not quite sure what.

Comment: The function you return from `once()` doesn't allow for function arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `fun`, you have to pass along the arguments you were given.

```js
once = function(fun){
  var beenCalled = false;
  var answer;
  return function() {
    if (beenCalled === true) {
      return answer;
    } else {
      beenCalled = true;
      answer = fun.apply(null, arguments);
      return answer;
    }
  }
};

var add = once(function(x,y,z) {
      return x + y + z;
});

console.log(add(1,2,3));
console.log(add(4,5,6));
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass in your arguments to `fun`. I used `apply` and `arguments` to pass in all the arguments.

```js
once = function(fun){
  var beenCalled = false;
  var answer;
  return function() {
    if (beenCalled === true) {
      return answer;
    } else {
      beenCalled = true;
      answer = fun.apply(this, arguments);
      return answer;
    }
  }
};

var add = once(function(x,y,z) {
      return x + y + z;
});

console.log(add(1,2,3));
console.log(add(4,5,6));
```